How to digital sign a pdf file using smartcard and iTextSharp?
I'm new in digital signing concept, I'm developing a winform application that allow an user to select a certificate from Windows certificate store, and use the selected certificate to sign to a pdf file, it is working perfectly when plug an usbtoken which contains the certificate and a midleware of the usbtoken installed, when I sign to a pdf file the midleware prompt me for entering pin and after enter the correct pin my application can easily sign to the pdf file. But when I try with a smartcard( TokenMe Evo – Bit4id) I can still get the certificate from windows store but when create signature by bellow line of code:
    IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(certificate, 
    "SHA-1");        

nothing promt me for entering pin and the bellow exception apear:
    System.ArgumentException: Unknown encryption algorithm 
    System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng

This is how i get the certificate from windows store:
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf.security;
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using X509Certificate = Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Tls;
    using System.Text.Json;
    using Serilog;
    using iTextSharp.text;

    private static IList<X509Certificate> chain = new List<X509Certificate>();
    private static X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

    X509CertificateParser cp = new X509CertificateParser();

    //Get Sertifiacte
    X509Store st = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    st.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
    X509Certificate2Collection collection = 
    X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(st.Certificates,
        "Please select certificate:", "", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
    if (collection.Count > 0)
    {
        certificate = collection[0];
    }
    if (certificate == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No certificate selected!");
        button3.Enabled = true;
        return;
    }
    st.Close();
    //Get Cert Chain

    X509Chain x509Chain = new X509Chain();

    x509Chain.Build(certificate);

    foreach (X509ChainElement x509ChainElement in x509Chain.ChainElements)
    {
        chain.Add(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509ChainElement.Certificate));
    }

And this is how I sign to the pdf file and the exception occur:
    private void signPdf(
        string inputFile, 
        string outputPath, 
        string imagePath, 
        int pageNum, 
        int position, 
        float imageWidth, 
        float imageHeight)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(inputFile);
            ouputFile = ouputFile + "\\" + fileName;
            PdfReader inputPdf = new PdfReader(inputFile);

            FileStream signedPdf = new FileStream(ouputFile, FileMode.Create);

            PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(inputPdf, signedPdf, 
            '\0');

            IExternalSignature externalSignature = 
            new X509Certificate2Signature(certificate, "SHA-1");

            PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = 
            pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;
            int NumberOfPages = inputPdf.NumberOfPages;
            if (imagePath != "" && imagePath != null)
            {
                signatureAppearance.SignatureGraphic = 
                iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
            }


            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = inputPdf.GetPageSize(pageNum);
            float x0 = 0;
            float y0 = 0;
            float x1 = 0;
            float y1 = 0;

            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    x0 = 0;
                    y0 = pageSize.Height - imageHeight;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    x0 = pageSize.Width - imageWidth;
                    y0 = pageSize.Height - imageHeight;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    x0 = 0;
                    y0 = 0;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    x0 = pageSize.Width - imageWidth;
                    y0 = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            x1 = x0 + imageWidth;
            y1 = y0 + imageHeight;
            signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
                x0, 
                y0, 
                x1, 
                y1), 
                pageNum, 
                GetOrganizationName(certificate));
            if (renderingMode == 0)
            {
                signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = 
                PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION;
            }
            else if (renderingMode == 1)
            {
                signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = 
                PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC;
            }
            else if (renderingMode == 2)
            {
                signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = 
                PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
            }

            MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, 
                null, null, null, 0,CryptoStandard.CMS);
            inputPdf.Close();
            pdfStamper.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.ToString());

    }
}

Please show me what am I doing wrong, Thanks a lot.

There is no SHA-1 . There is "SHA1"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithmname.sha1?view=net-8.0

@rene: "SHA-1" is from DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, your can refer DigestAlgorithms.SHA1,DigestAlgorithms.RIPEMD160, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, DigestAlgorithms.SHA384, DigestAlgorithms.SHA512, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1 return exact "SHA-1"

That might be true but your exception is from System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng  and that class doesn't know how to deal with SHA-1.  Can you give it a try to see if you get at least past that error with SHA1?

@rene, I just gave it a try, and still cause the same exception

For using tokens you should have a look at https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/part-iii-pkcs-11#PartIII-PKCS#11-HowtoAddressPKCS#11Driversin.NET

Try RSA or DSA (which means the PrivateKey should be in the form of RSACryptoServiceProvider or DSACryptoServiceProvider)

@jimi: unfortunately the PrivateKey is none of them: if (certificate.PrivateKey is RSACryptoServiceProvider)
{
encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";
return;
}
if (certificate.PrivateKey is DSACryptoServiceProvider)
{
encryptionAlgorithm = "DSA";
return;
}

@Glenner003: it look like a helpful link, I'll take a look

The you may need to rely on the workaround that should allow SHA-256 and SHA-512. The IExternalSignature wrapper seems to be quite restrictive

I resloved this issue myself. This is because of the private key of the certificate is not in form of RSA or DSA, its is actually:
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng

and the class X509Certificate2Signature from iTextSharp.text.pdf.security only implement two kind of certificate.PrivateKey are RSA and DSA like this:
public X509Certificate2Signature(X509Certificate2 certificate, string 
    hashAlgorithm)
{
    if (!certificate.HasPrivateKey)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("No private key.");
    }

    this.certificate = certificate;
    this.hashAlgorithm = 
    DigestAlgorithms.GetDigest(
        DigestAlgorithms.GetAllowedDigests(hashAlgorithm));
    if (certificate.PrivateKey is RSACryptoServiceProvider)
    {
        encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";
        return;
    }

    if (certificate.PrivateKey is DSACryptoServiceProvider)
    {
        encryptionAlgorithm = "DSA";
        return;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Unknown encryption algorithm " + 
    certificate.PrivateKey);
}

this is the cause of the Unknown encryption algorithm, beacuse when certificate.PrivateKey is System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng it won't set encryptionAlgorithm  and throw new ArgumentException, I cannot edit the class X509Certificate2Signature of namespace iTextSharp.text.pdf.security, so I created a class named X509Certificate2Signature1 myself implement IExternalSignature interface and add additional code to manipulate if certificate.PrivateKey is System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng, and bellow is how I implement my X509Certificate2Signature1 class:
public class X509Certificate2Signature1 : IExternalSignature
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The certificate with the private key
    private X509Certificate2 certificate;

    private string hashAlgorithm;

    private string encryptionAlgorithm;

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Creates a signature using a X509Certificate2. It supports 
    //smartcards without
    //     exportable private keys.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   certificate:
    //     The certificate with the private key
    //
    //   hashAlgorithm:
    //     The hash algorithm for the signature. As the Windows CAPI is 
    //used to do the signature
    //     the only hash guaranteed to exist is SHA-1
    public X509Certificate2Signature1(X509Certificate2 certificate, string 
        hashAlgorithm)
    {
        if (!certificate.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No private key.");
        }

        this.certificate = certificate;
        this.hashAlgorithm = 

        DigestAlgorithms.GetDigest(
            DigestAlgorithms.GetAllowedDigests(hashAlgorithm));
        if (certificate.PrivateKey is RSACryptoServiceProvider)
        {
            encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";
            return;
        }
        else if (certificate.PrivateKey is DSACryptoServiceProvider)
        {
            encryptionAlgorithm = "DSA";
            return;
        }
        else if (certificate.PrivateKey is 
            System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng)
        {
            encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";
            return;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Unknown encryption algorithm " + 
            certificate.PrivateKey);
    }

    public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
    {
        if (certificate.PrivateKey is RSACryptoServiceProvider)
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = 
               (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
            return rsa.SignData(message, hashAlgorithm);
        }
        else if (certificate.PrivateKey is 
           System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng)
        {
            System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng rSACng = 
              (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng)certificate.PrivateKey;
            return rSACng.SignData(message, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, 
                RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
        }
        else
        {
            DSACryptoServiceProvider dsa = 
                (DSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
            return dsa.SignData(message);
        }
    }

    public virtual string GetHashAlgorithm()
    {
        return hashAlgorithm;
    }

    public virtual string GetEncryptionAlgorithm()
    {
        return encryptionAlgorithm;
    }
}

And I change the line of code which cause the issue from:
externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(certificate, 
    "SHA-1");

To:
externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature1(certificate, 
    "SHA-1");

and now my application can digital signing to pdf files perfectly!

Exactly the way to go. Except that using SHA1 is clearly obsolete, SHA1 in document signatures is broken and trivial to forge. See https://shattered.io/
